# How to delete image with Intervention.io library for Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, intervention

I am using http://image.intervention.io/ library for Laravel 5.

I got everything working fine, but i cannot seem to find a delete()/remove() method.

Is this something that's not part of their library, because documentation doesn't mention it either. Or is there a "secret way" to unlink file via this library?

Comment: Why don't you just use the Filesystem library provided by Laravel? Use Intervention lib to operate with images, and then the Filesystem wrapper to operate on this files (move them, rename, delete, etc).

Comment: I ended up doing just that. I wanted to make sure i wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Laravel Filesystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#deleting-files)

```
Storage::delete('file.jpg');

Storage::delete(['file1.jpg', 'file2.jpg']);
```

InterventionImage library has no methods delete() or destroy().